# NoReverseMatch error following Python Crash Course Book

Tags: python, django

I have been working through the Django chapter of the Python Crash Course book and have run into an issue with the 'Create new entry' page. When I try to access the page it gives me this error:

#### NoReverseMatch at /topics/2/

```
Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new_entry/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']
```

and displays an error on my topic.html file:

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html'%}

{%block content%}

<p>Topic: {{topic}}</p>

<p>Entries:</p>
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">Add new entry</a>
</p>
<ul>
{%for entry in entries%}
    <li>
        <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </li>
{%empty%}
    <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>

{%endblock content%}
```

new_entry.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <p><a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

    <p>Add a new entry:</p>
    <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name='submit'>Add entry</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

As followed in the book I also wrote the view and URL path for the page

def new_entry in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Topic
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    #home page
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    #show topics
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics':topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    #show single topic and detail
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topics':topic, 'entries':entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)

def new_topic(request):
    #add new topic
    if request.method != 'POST':
        #no data submitted, create blank form
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted process data
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topics')
        
    #display blank or invalid form
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    #add new entry for particular topic
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #no data submitted, create blank form
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        #POST data submitted, process data
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit = False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic_id)
        
    #display blank or invalid form
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    #home page
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    #topics page
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    #detail page for single topic
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    #page for adding new topic
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    #page for adding new entry
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
]
```

I have checked multiple times and am unsure what is incorrect?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The problem comes when you try to display the `topic.html` page template, so you need to show us the code for that view.

Comment: The first block of code in my question is topic.html, but i have added new_entry.html which the view refers to.

Comment: Okay, that's the problem.  `topic.html` tries to access the `topic.id` variable, but the `topic()` view does **not** provide a variable named `topic` in the template context.

Comment: It feels like `topic.html` is supposed to have a `{% for topic in topics %}` loop, but it doesn't.

Comment: So the problem ended up being a typo that I wasn't seeing in the topic function in views.   `context = {'topics':topic, 'entries':entries}` should be  `context = {'topic':topic, 'entries':entries}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context in the topic function is passing 'topics' instead of 'topic'.

```
context = {'topics':topic, 'entries':entries}
```

should be

```
context = {'topic':topic, 'entries':entries}
```

Seems to be a simple typo.  The template html file is looking for the key 'topic'.  It doesn't fail on the {{ topic }} line, but does when you try to access topic.id.

```
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">Add new entry</a>
```

Comment: I would like to elaborate on why {{ topic }} does not fail, but I do not know the reason.  I could make some guesses, but I do not want to post incorrect information.